# Refreshing chart data in powerpoint 2010 is not executed via VBA

Tags: vba, charts, refresh, powerpoint

I try to update data of a chart in Powerpoint using this code:

```
Sub test1()
    Dim chrt As Chart
    Dim wbChart As New Workbook
    Dim wsChart As New Worksheet

    Dim sh As Shape

    With ActivePresentation.Slides(2)
        For Each sh In .Shapes
            If sh.Name = "Dia2" Then Exit For
        Next
    End With

    Set chrt = sh.Chart
    chrt.ChartData.Activate
    Set wbChart = chrt.ChartData.Workbook
    Set wsChart = wbChart.Worksheets(1)
    wsChart.Range("A2").Value = "North"
    wsChart.Range("A3").Value = "South"
    wsChart.Range("A4").Value = "East"
    wsChart.Range("A5").Value = "West"
    wsChart.Range("B1").Value = "2009"
    wsChart.Range("C1").Value = "2010"
    wsChart.Range("D1").Value = "2011"
    wsChart.ListObjects("Tabelle1").Resize wsChart.Range("A1:e6")
    wsChart.Range("A6").Value = "Canada"
    wsChart.Range("B6").Value = "5"
    wsChart.Range("C6").Value = "4"
    wsChart.Range("D6").Value = "3"
    wsChart.Range("E1").Value = "2012"
    wsChart.Range("E2").Value = "4"
    wsChart.Range("E3").Value = "5"
    wsChart.Range("E4").Value = "2"
    wsChart.Range("E5").Value = "3"
    wsChart.Range("E6").Value = "6"
    wbChart.Close

    sh.Chart.SetSourceData ("='Tabelle11'!$A$1:$E$6")
    sh.Chart.Refresh

End Sub
```

Everything works except the last to lines: sh.Chart.SetSourceData ("='Tabelle11!$A$1:$E$6") and sh.Chart.Refresh. The data itself is updated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is that you try to set Tabelle11 as source but you edit Tabelle1 and from what i've found, it should be ("='Tabelle1'!A1:E6")

HTH